# Extracting column of a column in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

In the below example I end of with an output of `3000 x 3000`, where it is temping to run `awk` again to get just the width and height as variables without white space.

```
$ cat << EOF >> /tmp/test
File name       : Graf3.png
File size       : 84937 Bytes
MIME type       : image/png
Image size      : 3000 x 3000
EOF
$ cat /tmp/test | awk -F':' '/Image size/ {print $2}'
 3000 x 3000
```

**Question**

Is there a way to get the width and height without calling `awk` again?

Comment: Please do mention how the final output should look like?

Comment: If you want the values in shell variables, you can use something like `IFS='x ' read w h <<< '3000 x 3000'` to get the values in `w` and `h`, but I'm not quite sure if you want them in shell or awk variables.

Comment: you have a file with content, you want to extract something without using awk? what else do you expect? grep or plain shell? the question is not clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bash: read from the output of a process substitution:

```
read -r width x height < <(awk -F':' '/Image size/ {print $2}' file)
echo "width=$width"
echo "height=$height"
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want the values in shell rather than awk variables:

```
$ dim=( $( awk '/Image size/{print $(NF-2), $NF}' file ) )
$ declare -p dim
declare -a dim=([0]="3000" [1]="3000")
```

Comment: Congratulations on your 100K and thank you for sharing your knowledge and insights these last few years. Oh, and happy 4th July!

Comment: Thanks for all the help and explanations! You showed me most of the things I know about awk.

Comment: @Ed Morton, many many Congrats for your 100K repo sir, well deserved, cheers, may GOD bless you and give strength to do more.

Comment: Thanks all for the good wishes, all the best to you too!

Comment: @EdMorton: Replicating  hek2mgl's words, all I know about `awk`, I've learned it from you! My utmost respects sir!

Answer (score 1):

Get `3000x3000` in one line by telling awk to use `": "` and `" x "` as field separators

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=": | x "} { if($0 ~ /Image size/) { print $2 "x" $3 }}' test.txt
```

Result:

```
3000x3000
```

Answer (score 1):

Not clear but if I am reading it correct in case you need 2 variables named height and width then keep it simple by simply creating 2 variables with simply printing their field numbers.

For height variable:

```
height=$(awk '{print $3}' Input_file)
```

For width variable:

```
width=$(awk '{print $5}'  Input_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` once you have the `$2` field desired:

```
$ awk -F':' '/Image size/{split($2,a,/[[:space:]]*x[[:space:]]*/); print a[1],a[2]}' test
3000 3000
```